# Define jacobian with tensorflow custom_gradient

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to define a [custom gradient in TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/custom_gradient) for a function that returns a non-scalar.

A simplified toy version of the problem is:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.custom_gradient
def f(x):
    y = tf.Variable([x[1], 2.0*x[0]])

    def grad(upstream):
        dg = tf.Variable([[0.0, 2.0], [1.0, 0.0]])
        return dg * upstream # ? no idea here

    return y, grad

x = tf.Variable([1.0, 2.0])
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    y = f(x)
tape.jacobian(y, x)
# tape.gradient(y,x)
```

I do not understand what shape the `grad` function needs to return.  In the above example, `tape.gradient` gives the full jacobian of the problem (which I would expect from `tape.jacobian`)and `tape.jacobian` gives nothing (though I had been getting error messages before restarting my kernel).

Is this the expected shape and behaviour?  What shape should the custom gradient return for a vector-valued or matrix-valued function's derivative?

Comment: It is unclear what your objective/desired outcome is. Your code does not reproduce the warning you've posted. See how to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Does this answer your question `In a pure mathematical sense, a vector-argument vector-valued function f's derivatives should be its Jacobian matrix J. Here we are expressing the Jacobian J as a function grad_fn which defines how J will transform a vector grad_ys when left-multiplied with it (grad_ys * J, the vector-Jacobian product, or VJP). This functional representation of a matrix is convenient to use for chain-rule calculation (in e.g. the back-propagation algorithm).` This statement is given in the [Tensorflow site](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/custom_gradient). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree it can be confusing. Let me try to expand the statement given in the [Tensorflow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/custom_gradient) and draw an explicit link between the maths and the code.

Let us consider a function

[image: f:\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n].

Its Jacobian is the *n* x *m* matrix:

[image: \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1}&\cdots&\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_m}\\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\frac{\partial f_n}{\partial x_1}&\cdots&\frac{\partial f_n}{\partial x_m} \end{bmatrix}].

Given an input vector *x* and an "upstream" vector *u*, the function `grad_fn` in a `@custom_gradient` function should return the "vector-Jacobian product" vjp, i.e.:

[image: \mathrm{vjp}(f)(u, x) = u^\top \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x)].

Note that in this formulation *u* is given and does not depend on *x*. Therefore, we can rewrite the vjp as follows:

[image: \mathrm{vjp}(f)(u, x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}((u^\top f(x))].

This can be generalised to higher-rank tensors if we define [image: <a,b>] as the sum of the elementwise product of *a* and *b* (i.e. `tf.reduce_sum(a * b)`), which is the regular dot product for vectors and the [Frobenius inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product) for matrices. Then, the output of `grad_fn` should be a tensor with the same shape as *x* computed as:

[image: \Big(\mathrm{vjp}(f)(u, x)\Big){i,j,\dots} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x{i,j,\dots}}\langle u,f(x)\rangle].

Note that this is effectively the gradient of the scalar-valued function `tf.reduce_sum(u * f(x))` (and is therefore easier to think about and to work with).

---

In your specific case, you need to take the gradient of `u[0]*x[1]+u[1]*2.0*x[0]` with respect to `x[0],x[1]`, i.e. something like:

```python
def grad(upstream):
    return tf.Variable([2.0*upstream[1], upstream[0]])
```

This produces the desired gradient.

Unfortunately `jacobian` won't work with this (as it doesn't with your original code) because your code has a second issue: by using variables it breaks the link between the outputs and the inputs (creating a variable is like copy/pasting the values and does not propagate the gradients). You can fix this as follows:

```python
@tf.custom_gradient
def f(x):
    y = tf.stack([x[1], 2.0*x[0]])

    def grad(upstream):
        return tf.stack([2.0*upstream[1], upstream[0]])

    return y, grad
```